# Reversing extracted HTML table data order in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have this code in js file

```
  var tbl_html = '<table class="table table-condensed grid" width="350px" border="1">' +
                  '<thead>';

  var tbl_html_processing = '<table class="table table-condensed"  width="150px" border="1">' +
                           '<thead>';


        tbl_html = tbl_html + '<tr><th width="300px" nowrap="yes" ><center>ProductionDate</br></center></th>' +
        '<th width="250px" nowrap="yes" ><center>Processing StartTime</center></th>' +
                   '<th width="250px"  nowrap="yes" ><center>Processing EndTime</center></th>' +
                   '<th width="250px" ><center>Processing TotalTime</center></th></tr>' +
                   '</thead>';

          tbl_html = tbl_html + '<tbody>' +


                         '<td>' + yearconvert(yearr) + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + st_time_formated + st_time_am_pm + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + ed_time_formated + ed_time_am_pm + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + dur_time_formated + '</td>';
```

Data is extracted in an order but I want to flip last row as a first and other rows will follow accordingly

Here is the current one
[image]

I want to resolve this issue using html stuff , giving id to 'td' tags and converting it.
Any idea ?

Comment: When looping through the dataset loop in other order. Or if getting from DB, set order by in your query.

Comment: How are you getting the data? Probably you can assign priority number to the rows while you are extracting the data.

Comment: there is a for loop  , and it puts them in an order , but if I change the order I breaks the loop because it gives minus ajax numbers

Comment: Do you want to reverse the order, or just the last row to become the first and the rest of them to stay intact?

Comment: Simply use `Array.reverse()`, for example:
    
    `var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.reverse(); // [3,2,1]`